# Neo4j Batch Inserter Unknown Error

Tags: neo4j, batch-insert

I am attempting to use the java batch-inserter for a neo4j database, and I get the following error message:

```
>java -server -Xmx4G -jar target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target/db nodes6.csv, rels5.csv

Using Existing Configuration File
Nodes file nodes6.csv, does not exist

Total import time: 0 seconds 
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.graphdb.NotFoundException: id=4621
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.getNodeRecord(BatchInserterImpl.java:915)
    at org.neo4j.unsafe.batchinsert.BatchInserterImpl.createRelationship(BatchInserterImpl.java:468)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.importRelationships(Importer.java:108)
    at org.neo4j.batchimport.Importer.main(Importer.java:63)
```

Nodes6.csv most certainly exists, so this is... confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 errors here, the first is that it's unable to locate your nodes6.csv file, to me it looks like you entered the file name with an extra `,`.

What you have:
`java -server -Xmx4G -jar target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target/db nodes6.csv, rels5.csv`

Should it be this: `java -server -Xmx4G -jar target/batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target/db nodes6.csv rels5.csv`

Comment: Yes it should. I'm stunned that you picked this up!